# exim4 vs gmail FROM field

Tags: smtp, gmail, google-apps, exim4

I've configured exim on my server as MTA to work with gmail.
Here is a configuration:

```
gmail_login:
       driver = plaintext
       public_name = LOGIN
       client_send = : myaccount1@gmail.com : mypassword
```

The configuration is OK and I'm able to send a mail using a php script:

```
$to      = 'myaccount3@gmail.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: myaccount2@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: myaccount2@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
  echo 'mail() Success!' . "<br />\n";
}
else {
  echo 'mail() Failure!' . "<br />\n";
}
```

However I've encountered an issue:

gmail shows myaccount1@gmail.com in the FROM field instead of the actual email specified in the FROM field in my script (myaccount2@gmail.com).
The reply-to field is OK.

Please, help to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Gmail overwrites any FROM value you specify. Gmail overwrites it with the authenticated FROM value.